# How to use Jquery to make a button disapear and then reapear?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data that when I click on `Show More` it shows the data and the `Show More` disappears. The data and a new button `Show Less` appears. When I click on the `Show Less` the data disappears again. How can I make the `Show More` appear back once `Show Less` is clicked?

My HTML Code is:

```
<button id="show">Show More</button>
<div id="complete">
    <img src="Pictures/xerox.png" height="20%" width="20%">
</div>
<p>
<button id="hide">Show Less</button>
```

My Jquery Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass("more");
        $(this).hide();
        $("#complete").show();
    });

    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#complete").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that did work. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your jQuery is telling the object making the call to hide itself when clicked:

```
$(this).hide();
```

Based on your description, I would recommend adding the following to your function that handles the Show Less function:

```
$('#show').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the question this is what you want

```
<style>
 #complete{
 display:none;
}
 #hide{
 display:none;
}
</style>

<button id="show">Show More</button>
<div id="complete">
 <img src="Pictures/xerox.png" height="20%" width="20%">
</div>
<p>
<button id="hide">Show Less</button>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#show").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().addClass("more");
      $(this).hide();
      $("#hide").show();
      $("#complete").show();
  });

  $("#hide").click(function(){
      $("#complete").hide();
      $("#show").show();
      $("#hide").hide();
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: copy and paste this into the browser and you will start seeing the behavior you wanted